# Does it uniformly convergence?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Does $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1 \over n}-{1\over n+x}$$ converge uniformly on any bounded interval including x?

Comment: It isn't even defined  for every $x$.

Answer (score 3):

If $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded and $A' = A \setminus \{-1, -2, -3, ...\}$ then for each $x \in A'$ the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+x} \right) = x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + nx}
$$
converges.

Now 
\begin{align}
\left| \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+x} \right) - \sum_{n=1}^k \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+x} \right) \right| &\leq \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \left| \frac{x}{n^2+nx} \right| \\
&= |x| \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{1}{|n^2+nx|}\,.
\end{align}
If $x \geq 0$, then $\frac{1}{n^2 + nx} \leq \frac{2}{n^2}$. If $x < 0$, then for large enough $n$ we have $nx > -n^2/2$. Thus for large enough $k$ we have
$$
|x| \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{1}{|n^2+nx|} \leq |x| \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2}
$$
for all $x \in A'$. Since $A'$ is bounded, we have $|x| \leq C$ for all $x \in A'$ for some constant $C$. This implies that the series converges uniformly on $A'$.

Especially the series converges uniformly on all bounded intervals that do not contain any negative integers.